# Is it worth to check the corpses in Lower Kurast (Diablo II)?

Tags: diablo-ii

The fastest way to get high runes in Diablo II Single Player is considered to be Lower Kurast running. You reroll your map until you get a map with 6 Superchests close to your Lower Kurast Waypoint. There are always 3 Superchests and a corpse next to a bonfire in lower kurast and I always wondered if it is worth it to invest the extra time to check the guaranteed corpse. It probably just takes around 2 seconds per run, but when doing hundereds or even thousands of runs it makes a big difference, when a run takes around 15-20 seconds.

That beeing said, I have seen people on YouTube drop the desired Ber-Rune and I myself dropped it from a corpse before. But although the odds of the superchests are clear (~ 2 / 65k) I am not sure about the odds of the corpses. Following up that question: there are many other popables in Lower Kurast. Is it worth to check those if they are on your path to the superchests?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the wikis don't show much information beyond a physical description of what the corpse containers are, and what they do:

> Dead bodies are a type of container holding potential treasure. […] Clicking a dead body will move it slightly and reveal any items or gold that was hidden on it.

[Source](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Dead_body)

> Corpses: The bodies of fallen warriors often litter the areas you traverse, and can be searched for loot.

[Source](https://diablo.gamepedia.com/Containers)

The only list of chance to drop specific items from a container I have found is [this one](http://members.iinet.net.au/~dcarson/drop_summary.html). Again, there is no evidence that this list is linked to corpses, but it does not specify anything beyond "Chests" or "Locked Chests"; though it does specify the "No Drop %" varies for different containers. Take that as you may.

According to this list, the chance of a Chest dropping a Rune is a 4.8% chance that it will be "good" loot, and another 10.8% chance that loot will be a rune; however this has up to 4 chances to drop this (if I'm reading this correctly).

---

At this point, this is the only information I have been able to find to support any hard values regarding a chance for a corpse to drop any specific loot, so I don't think there is any hard answer for this yet, without some more specific testing.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But I know for a fact that it is known and I myself already dove into that stuff: https://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Guide:Rune_Finder_Guide_v1.10,_by_Urlik#Objects_.28Chest_TC.29. This became to complicated for me.